# Update Final SQL Table with Temp Table using select max for Column

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Good day all! What I want to do is update `FinalTable` with a temp table, where the `DateStamp` Column of The temp table is greater then `DateStamp` column in the `FinalTable`

So far I have come up with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FinalTable]([DateStamp], [TIME], [DATE], [USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME], [MODEL_NAME], [SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER], [SCORECARD_NAME],[ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER], [ELEMENT_NAME], [SERIES_IDENTIFIER], [SERIES_NAME],[PERIOD_NAME], [ACTION_TYPE], [ACTION], [PREVIOUS_VALUE], [VALUE], [UNIT])
   SELECT 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONCAT([DATE], ' ' ,[TIME]), 121) AS [DateStamp],
       [TIME], [DATE], [USER_LOGIN], [USER_NAME],
       [MODEL_NAME], [SCORECARD_IDENTIFIER], [SCORECARD_NAME],
       [ELEMENT_IDENTIFIER], [ELEMENT_NAME],
       [SERIES_IDENTIFIER], [SERIES_NAME],
       [PERIOD_NAME], [ACTION_TYPE], [ACTION], 
       [PREVIOUS_VALUE], [VALUE], [UNIT]
   FROM 
       #TEMP 
   WHERE
       (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONCAT([DATE], ' ' ,[TIME]), 121) AS [DateStamp] FROM #TEMP) > (SELECT MAX([DateStamp]) FROM [Test].[dbo].[FinalTable])

   DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Unfortunately it gives me an error like this:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The `[DateStamp]` column in the temp is being created in the select because I am reading a text file. So initially I want to check the two tables and where the `[DateStamp]` column value is higher in `#Temp` then the one in the `[FinalTable]` just add/insert the new rows into `[FinalTable]`

If anyone suggests something else do let me know. I'm still a newbie to SQL but I'm trying what I can.

Comment: The issue is "SELECT convert(varchar,CONCAT([DATE], ' ' ,[TIME]), 121) AS [DateStamp] FROM #TEMPMetricsServerAudit" is returning more than 1 record. I would suggest using JOIN instead of using sub query.

Comment: It would bring back more then 1 value. The temp is being populated from a text file that gets updated with new lines daily.

Comment: What is #TEMPMetricsServerAudit table ? Is it same as #Temp?

Comment: Lol Its supposed to be sorry let me change that! Sorry i Change the Names so we left with easy names Like Temp and not the actual names that are lengthy

Comment: Try this "INSERT INTO [dbo].[FinalTable]([DateStamp],[TIME],[DATE]..)
SELECT convert(varchar,CONCAT([DATE], ' ' ,[TIME]), 121) AS [DateStamp],[TIME],[DATE]
FROM #TEMP T where convert(varchar,CONCAT(T.[DATE], ' ' ,T.[TIME]), 121) > (Select MAX([DateStamp]) FROM [Test].[dbo].[FinalTable])" .Also i do not recommend using varchar while comparing dates.

Comment: Thank You Dalton! Make your comments an answer and i will chose it as right!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FinalTable]([DateStamp],[TIME],[DATE]..) 
SELECT convert(varchar,CONCAT([DATE], ' ' ,[TIME]), 121) AS [DateStamp],[TIME],[DATE] 
FROM #TEMP T 
where convert(varchar,CONCAT(T.[DATE], ' ' ,T.[TIME]), 121) > (Select MAX([DateStamp]) FROM [Test].[dbo].[FinalTable])
```

Also I do not recommend using varchar while comparing dates

Answer (score 0):

Problem here:

```
where (SELECT convert(varchar,CONCAT([DATE], ' ' ,[TIME]), 121) AS [DateStamp] FROM #TEMP)
```

Here is no condition on #TEMP

Comment: If i change it to this:  `FROM #TEMPMetricsServerAudit where (Select [DateStamp] FROM #TEMPMetricsServerAudit) > (Select MAX([DateStamp]) FROM [Test].[dbo].[MetricsServerAudit])`

it give me an error saying: `Invalid column name 'DateStamp'.`

Comment: Try `where convert(varchar,CONCAT([DATE], ' ' ,[TIME]), 121)` instead of expression in answer

Comment: Thanks to you too mnv!